# Asymptotic behaviour of the Incomplete $\Gamma$-funtion

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

As part of an assignment, we had to investigate the asymptotic behaviour as $n$ tends to $+\infty$ of the ratio
$$\frac{\Gamma(n,n|z|^2)}{\Gamma(n)},$$ where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is defined as $$\Gamma(s,x)=\int_x^{+\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d} t.$$
In the cases $|z|>1$ and $|z|<1,$ I was able to use a steepest descent analysis on the integral to prove $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n,n|z|^2)}{\Gamma(n)}\right)=\begin{cases}
  1 &\text{ if } |z|<1,\\
  0 &\text{ if } |z|>1.
 \end{cases}$$

The case $|z|=1$ is not part of the assignment, but I am curious about the limit in this case. Numerical reseach using WolframAlpha suggests $1/2$, but I don't see how to prove this value. Is the numerical value correct and how can one proof this?

Comment: $$\Gamma(n,n)=n^n\int_1^\infty e^{-n(x-\ln x)}\frac{dx}x$$
then use the Laplace method ($f(x)=x-\ln x$ has an extremum (minimum) at $x=1$)

Comment: Why can we use the Laplace method? Isn't the problem that the extremum is exactly at 1, which is at the edge of the integration domain?

Comment: We can use the Laplace method in the case of the extremum at the bound of integration as well.

Comment: When I work it out using this representation, I get $$\Gamma(n,n)=n^n\int_1^{+\infty}e^{-n(x-\ln(x))}\approx n^n\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n}}e^{-n}.$$ Similarly, $$\Gamma(n)=n^n\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-n(x-\ln(x))}\approx n^n\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n}}e^{-n},$$ so the limit is one. However, one could do exactly the same analysis for $\gamma(s,x) = \int_0^xt^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$ and also get that $$\frac{\gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)}\rightarrow 1.$$ Then we have shown $$1=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n)}=\frac{\gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)}+\frac{\gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)}\rightarrow2.$$ Where is the mistake in this reasonining?

Comment: $$\Gamma(n,n)=n^n\int_1^\infty e^{-n(x-\ln x)}\frac{dx}x\sim \Gamma(n,n)=n^ne^{-n}\int_1^\infty e^{-n\frac{(t-1)^2}2}dt=n^ne^{-n}\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\sqrt{\frac2n}$$